# Saving unwanted data to an error file

Tags: c, function, pointers, if-statement, struct

Hi I currently have a piece of code that grabs names from a file and then saves it to another.

However I would now like to save any invalid information to a fixed error file and was wondering how I'd go about it

My code:

Struct:

```
struct Person{
    char fName[16];     //string to store the persons first name
    char lName[21];     //string to store the persons last name
};
```

Main

```
int main(){
    int recordCount = 0;    //used to keep track of the number of records currently in memory
    struct Person *records;

    records = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));

    records = open(&recordCount, records);
    records = addRecord(&recordCount, records);
    save(recordCount, records);
    return 0;                   //End the program and return 0 to the operating system
}
```

open(&recordCount, records) function:

```
struct Person* open(int *rCount, struct Person *records){
  FILE *recordFile;
  char fileName[30] = {'\0'};
  int i = *rCount;
  char test;


  puts("Enter a filename to open :");
  scanf("%s", fileName);

  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"r"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
      exit(1);
  }
  else{

      test = fscanf(recordFile,"%s %s", records[i].fName,records[i].lName);
      while(test!= EOF){
          i++;
          records = realloc(records,(i+1)*sizeof(struct Person));
          test = fscanf(recordFile,"%s %s", records[i].fName,records[i].lName);
      }
      fclose(recordFile); // close the file
  }
  *rCount = i;
  return records;    //add i (records read from the file) to rCount (the current record count)
}
```

addRecord(&recordCount, records) function

```
struct Person* addRecord(int* rCount, struct Person *records){

int valid = 0;  //used to indicated valid input
int length = 0; //used to store the string lengths
int i = 0;    //used in the for loops
char fNameTest[16];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records
char lNameTest[21];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records

//Checking the length of data input for fName
do{
    length = strlen(fNameTest);
    if(length < 16){
        for(i=0;i<=length;i++)                      
            records[*rCount].fName[i] = fNameTest[i]; //if correct insert the record at the index determined by rCount
        valid=1;
    }
    else{

        valid = 0;
    }

}while(valid!=1);

//Checking the length of data input for lName
do{
    length = strlen(lNameTest);
    if(length < 21){
        for(i=0;i<=length;i++)                    
            records[*rCount].lName[i] = lNameTest[i]; //if correct insert the record at the index determined by rCount
        valid=1;
        (*rCount)++;                                   //At this point ID,fName and lName have been stored so increment rCount
    }
    else{

        valid = 0;
    }

}while(valid!=1);


records = realloc(records,((*rCount)+1)*sizeof(struct Person));
return records;  //return rCount as the new updated recordCount
}
```

save(recordCount, records) function

```
void save(int rCount, struct Person *records){
  FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
  char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
  int i;

  puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
  scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                    //here in your program

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of Person's to it
      for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
          fprintf(recordFile,"%s %s\n",records[i].fName,records[i].lName);
      }
      fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
      printf("Records saved to file: %s\n",fileName);
  }

}
```

I was thinking of removing the do-while loops in the addRecords function and replacing them with if statements. And then finally an if statement to check the value of valid. And then if valid=0 point to a function or save the errorfile directly there.

However I am unsure if this is the best way to go (or if my thought process would even work) and wondered if anyone could help.

Edit: Decided to add the type of data I'm dealing with incase anyone wants to create a .txt and run the program

```
Bob Jones
Franklin Davies
James Donut
```

EDIT Following the answer below I have updated my code (edited segments below)

EDITED saveFunction

```
void save(int rCount, struct Person *records){
  FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
  char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
  int i;

  puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
  scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                    //here in your program

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of Person's to it

char fileName[sizeof (struct Person) * 2];  // twice needed size

while (fgets(fileName, sizeof fileName, recordFile) != NULL) {
struct Person P;

int n;  // Save index where scanning stopped
int cnt = sscanf(fileName,"%15s%21s %n", P.fName, P.lName, &n);
if (cnt != 2 || fileName[n]) {
  errorLine(fileName);
  // do not increment i;
} else {
  // Good to keep
  // realloc memory as needed here
  records[i] = P;
  i++;
  }

}
```

errorLine function:

```
void errorLine(char *fileName)
{
FILE *errorFile;

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((errorFile = fopen("error.txt","w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file:\n");
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of Person's to it
      for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
          fprintf(errorFile,"%i %s %s\n",records[i].fName,records[i].lName);
      }
      fclose(errorFile);   //close the file
      printf("Records saved to file: %s\n",fileName);
  }
}
```

No doubt I probably implemented the answer incorrectly and now get an error:

```
error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Which is found on my last line of the program

Comment: Rather than `errorLine(char *fileName)`, use `errorLine(char *fileName, const char *buf) ....  fopen("error.txt","a")) ... fprintf(errorFile,"(%s)\n", buf);`  `"a"` to append, rather than `"w"` to write anew.  Write the `buffer`, not the improperly filled `records[i]`.  No `for()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to limit length of input *before* attempting to save in structure.

```
else {
  char buffer[sizeof (struct Person) * 2];  // twice needed size
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, recordFile) != NULL) {
    struct Person P;

    int n;  // Save index where scanning stopped
    int cnt = sscanf(buffer,"%15s%21s %n", P.fName, P.lName, &n);
    if (cnt != 2 || buffer[n] || MaybeAddtionalTests(&P)) {
      SaveBadLine(buffer);
      // do not increment i;
    } else {
      // Good to keep
      // realloc memory as needed here
      records[i] = P;
      i++;
    }
  }
  fclose(recordFile); // close the file
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit new to C, but I take it your answer is being implemented at else statement within the save function?

A couple of other things I don't quite understand is the MaybeAdditionalTests and SaveBadLine is it possible to expand on what I would put in there place?

Comment: @Funkii Yes - implemented after `else`.  First name and last name are certainly limited in length due to `"%15s%21s"`.  Candidate additional tests: check if the string is only letters.  Test if the first letter is capitalized, etc.  For bad records, open a file and append the string in `buffer`.  These are just place-holder functions for the code.

Comment: edited my answer, thank you for the additional tests but just for this purpose I don't need to implement them :) 

However no doubt I have probably messed up inputting your answer into my code, anymore help would be great

Comment: @Funkii See above comments.  Likely need `records = realloc(records,(i+1)*sizeof(struct Person));` in place of comment `// realloc memory as needed here`.  It is important that not only you edit your code, but that you understand it.

Comment: @Funkii A difference between original code and this answer: original code added bad records to `records` and then tried to test them.  This answer tests the line before attempting to add it to `records`and only adds it if it is good.